# Symfony/htaccess: add /home to index url

Tags: .htaccess, symfony, routes

I feel a bit bad and ashamed about asking this but I have looked all over Google and did not find an answer to my question. At least none I have been able to understand properly. 
I'm facing an issue with the knppaginatorbundle and symfony. I discovered that my pagination wasn't working with the basic / route but it was actually working with a route like so /home.

My question is, how can I modify my .htaccess symfony's file to redirect users from www.example.com to www.example.com/home?

Here is my .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    #<IfModule mod_vhost_alias.c>
    #    RewriteBase /
    #</IfModule>

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]

</IfModule>

<files php.ini>
  order deny,allow
  deny from all
</files>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well actually I found the answer and it's not in the .htaccess  .. I'm afraid I'm the proof that I should think before I speak :P

So I ended by making of my indexAction() in my controller a simple redirection to another route that was calling another action listAction() in the same controller. This listAction naturally contains what the indexAction() initially contained. Is that clear enough? here is the code ;)

```
<?php

namespace Pf\Bundle\BlogBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('pf_blog_index2'));
    }

    public function listAction()
    {
        $em    = $this->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
        $dql   = "SELECT a FROM PfBlogBundle:Projects a ORDER by a.id DESC";
        $query = $em->createQuery($dql);

        $paginator  = $this->get('knp_paginator');
        $pagination = $paginator->paginate(
            $query,
            $this->get('request')->query->get('page', 1)/*page number*/,
            8 /*limit per page */
         );

        // Puis modifiez la ligne du render comme ceci, pour prendre en compte l'article :
        return $this->render('PfBlogBundle:Default:home.html.twig', array('pagination'=>$pagination));
    }

}
```

And the routes:

```
pf_blog_index:
    path:  /
    defaults: { _controller: PfBlogBundle:Home:index }

pf_blog_index2:
    path:  /home
    defaults: { _controller: PfBlogBundle:Home:list }
```

NOW it sounds pretty obvious to me but I guess it depends what point of view you have. I feel a bit ashamed yet I'm sure it will be beneficial for someone like me in the future.